# If $A⊈B∪C$ then $A-B⊈C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This is the statement that needs to be proved: If $A⊈B∪C$  then   $A-B⊈C$. 
I want to proof using the contrapositive, so: If $A-B⊆C$  then   $A⊆B∪C.$

And I don't know what to do from this point on.

Comment: Try starting by writing out what $x \in A - B$ means. It is pretty straightforward after that

Comment: If you do not have to use contrapositive, note that $A\not\subseteq B\cup C$ means that tehre is some $x\in A$ with $x\notin B\cup C$

Answer (score 1):

If A-B⊆C,
suppose $x \in A$.

If $x \in B$,
then
$x \in B \cup C$.

If $x \not\in B$,
then
$x \in A-B$,
so $x \in C$,
so $x \in B \cup C$.

Therefore
$x \in A 
\implies x \in B \cup C$,
so
$A \subseteq B \cup C
$.

Answer (score 0):

$A \not \subseteq B \cup C$ means there is an $x_0 \in A$ where $x_0 \not \in B \cup C$.

That means $x_0 \not \in B$ and $x_0 \not \in C$.  But $x_0 \in A$ and $x_0 \not \in B$ means $x_0 \in A - B$.

But $x_0 \not \in C$.  So $A - B \not \subseteq C$.

====

Furthermore, FWIW, this proves $A - (B \cup C) \subseteq A-B$.